# how to acess variabale with different "last name" in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am using 15 text boxes in creating a visual basic application. The text boxes are named from 'TB1' through 'TB15'. I now want to copy the value to a 2d array named 'a'. How should i do this please help with the code below

```
For i = 0 To 4 Step 1     
  For j = 0 To 2 Step 1
    a(i, j) = Convert.ToInt32(TB1.Text)    
  Next
Next
```

how should i modify the line `a(i, j) = Convert.ToInt32(TB1.Text)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step is always +1 by default, so that is not needed. You can access a control by name by calling Controls() and have complete access to the object.

```
    Dim Counter As Long = 0
    For i = 0 To 4
        For j = 0 To 2
            Counter += 1
            a(i, j) = Convert.ToInt32(Controls("TB" & Counter.ToString).Text)
        Next
    Next
```